# Looping Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to loop through an Excel worksheet and to store the values based on a unique ID in a text file.

I am having trouble with the loop and I have done research on it with no luck and my current nested loop continually overflows. Instead of updating the corresponding cell when the control variable is modified, it continues to store the initial Index value for all 32767 iterations.

Please can someone explain why this is happening, and provide a way of correcting it?.

```
Sub SortLetr_Code()
'sort columns for Letr_Code files

    Dim lr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:B" & lr).Sort key1:=Range("B2"), order1:=1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Value of cell for example B1 starts out as X
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = 2
    y = 2

'Cell References

    Dim rwCounter As Range
    Dim rwCorresponding As Range
    Dim rwIndexValue As Range
    Dim rwIndexEnd As Range
    Dim rwIndexStore As Range

    'Variables for files that will be created
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Filetype As String

    'Variables defined
    FilePath = "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\SURLOAD\"
    Filetype = ".dat"

    'Use Cell method for Loop
    rwIndex = Cells(x, "B").Value
    Set rwCounter = Range("B" & x)

    'Use Range method for string manipulation
    Set rwCorresponding = Range("A" & x)
    Set rwIndexValue = Range("B" & y)
    Set rwIndexStore = Range("B" & x)
    Set rwIndexEnd = Range("B:B").End(xlUp)

    'Objects for creating the text files
    Dim FileCreate As Object
    Set FileCreate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Object for updating the file during the loop
    Dim FileWrite As Object

    For Each rwIndexStore In rwIndexEnd.Cells
        'Get Substring of cell value in BX for the file name
        Do Until IsEmpty(rwCounter)

            Filename = Mid$(rwIndexValue, 7, 5)
            Set FileWrite = FileCreate.CreateTextFile(FilePath + Filename + Filetype)

            'Create the file
            FileWrite.Write (rwCorresponding & vbCrLf)

            Do
                'Add values to the textfile
                x = x + 1
                FileWrite.Write (rwCorresponding & vbCrLf)

            Loop While rwCounter.Value Like rwIndexValue.Value

            'Close this file
            FileWrite.Close

            y = x
        Loop
    Next rwIndexStore

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
Sub GURMAIL_File()
'sort columns for Letr_Code files
    Dim lr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:B" & lr).Sort key1:=Range("B2"), order1:=1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Variables that store cell number
    Dim Corresponding As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer

    Corresponding = 2
    Index = 2
    Counter = 2

    'Cell References
    Dim rwIndexValue As Range

    'Variables for files that will be created
    Dim l_objFso As Object
    Dim FilePath As String

    Dim Total As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Filetype As String
    Dim FolderName As String

    'Variables defined
    FilePath = "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\SURLOAD\"
    'Name of the folder to be created
    FolderName = Mid$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 9, 8) & "\"
    'Folder path
    Total = FilePath & FolderName
    'File Extension
    Filetype = ".dat"

    'Object that creates the folder
    Set l_objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Objects for creating the text files
    Dim FileCreate As Object
    Set FileCreate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Object for updating the file during the loop
    Dim FileWrite As Object

    'Get Substring of letter code in order to name the file. End this loop once ID field is null.
    Do While Len(Range("A" & Corresponding)) > 0
        'Create the directory if it does not exist
        If Not l_objFso.FolderExists(Total) Then
            l_objFso.CreateFolder (Total)
        End If

        'Refence to cell containing a letter code
        Set rwIndexValue = Range("B" & Index)
        'Substring of that letter code
        Filename = Mid$(rwIndexValue, 7, 5)
        'Create the file using the substring and store it in the proper location
        Set FileWrite = FileCreate.CreateTextFile(Total + Filename + Filetype, True)

        'For each letter code, find the corresponding values. End the loop once the last value for the letter code is stored.
        Do While Range("B" & Index) Like Range("B" & Counter)
            'Add each line to the text file.
            FileWrite.WriteLine (Range("A" & Corresponding))

            'Incrementer variables that allow you to exit the loop
            'if you have reached the last value of the current letter code.
            Corresponding = Corresponding + 1
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Loop

        'Close the file you were writing to
        FileWrite.Close

        'Make sure that Index value is updated to the next letter code
        Index = Counter
        'In case Index value needs updating (safeguard to make sure that the new letter code is stored to index value).
        Set rwIndexValue = Range("B" & Index)

    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a place you are setting `rwCounter` inside the loop.

It looks like it would stay on range("B2") and x would just continue to increase until it hits an error, either at the limit of integer or long.

add `Set rwCounter = Range("B" & x)` somewhere inside your loop to increment it

Comment: Setting rwCounter and rwCorresponding fixed the problem with incrementing. Thank you for your help.